# Extract minimum values only in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Quantity_Limit   Cost   Wholesaler_Code
  2           9.2         1
  2           9.4         1
  2           7.1         2

  4           10.2        1
  4           4.1         2
  4           2.1         3
```

And I would like to create the following dataframe, with only Wholesalers that offer the minimum Cost, for the same quantity limit, without using a for loop:

```
Quantity_Limit   Cost   Wholesaler_Code
  2           7.1         2

  4           2.1         3
```

I tried with:

```
df.groupby(["Quantity_Limit", "Wholesaler_Code"], as_index = False).agg({"Cost": "min"})
```

but I don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort `Quantity_Limit`, `Cost` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['Quantity_Limit', 'Cost']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Quantity_Limit'])

Out[1121]:
   Quantity_Limit  Cost  Wholesaler_Code
2  2               7.1   2
5  4               2.1   3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` to create a column with the minimum values and filter based on those.

```
df["min_cost"] = df.groupby(["Quantity_Limit"])["Cost"].min()
df[df["Cost"] == df["min_cost"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also groupby and join the result df to the original df to get the left over column:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Quantity_Limit'])['Cost'].min().reset_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df, on = ['Quantity_Limit', 'Cost'], how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
   Quantity_Limit  Cost  Wholesaler_Code
0               2   7.1                2
1               4   2.1                3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

#Raw data
data = [[2, 9.2,1], [2, 9.4,1], [2,7.1,1],[4, 10.2,1], [4, 4.1,2], [4,2.1,3]]


# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Quantity_Limit', 'Cost','Wholesaler_Code']) 

# Group by to find minimum using variable "Cost" . It will create a variable min_Cost
df["min_cost"] =df.groupby(["Quantity_Limit"])["Cost"].min()
```

[image: Output from above code]

Now from above output we will filter the rows where min_cost is not equal to NaN

```
df1=df[df["min_cost"]>0]
```

And you will get your desired output.

[image: Final Desired Output]